# How to Bind the SQL DataBase Table to DevExpress XtraScheduler control?

Tags: c#

I'm Working With XtraScheduler Control to show the user event in day wise. As I Followed   the Video Given in Google. I can Bind the DataBase Table to XtraScheduler Control. while running the project it loads the database data in dataset. But the Problem is xtrascheduler control  doesn't display the data in xtrascheduler . i need to display the particular data With starting and ending date . Even the user can see the Upcoming Events in xtrascheduler control for future reference. can any one help me .

***Note:***
**DataBase table columns:**

```
create table EventReg(ID bigint, EventTitle varchar(255),EventNotes varchar(255), Category varchar(255), Schedule varchar(255), EventStatus varchar(255), StartDate date, EndDate date, StartTime time, EndTime time, EventPlace varchar(255),  ContactPerson varchar(255),  MobileNo varchar(255), GuestName varchar(255), ConductedBy varchar(255), OtherInfo varchar(255), Remark varchar(255))
```

**XrtaScheduler Control Event View:**

Starting Date, Ending Date, Category, EventTitle

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few steps to get it working.  I assume its DevExpress Scheduler.

1. You *may* need to explicitly set your Appointment.Mappings.. The field names are case sensitive.
2. You need to cast your Start and End times as SMALLDATETIME SQL objects. 
   Like this:

Select CAST(YourTimeField AS SMALLDATETIME) AS StartTime .  The Start and End times also need to be complete with DATE and TIME information.

Hope this helps